# Why does the display function interfere with text-align?

Tags: css, html

Alright, so I'm trying to make a line of different text bits in html/css. This will be the precursor for a navbar. My HTML is:

```
<div id="navBar">
<p class="navBartext">About</p>
<p class= "navbartext">News</p>
<p class= "navbartext">Contact Us</p>
<p class= "navbartext">Jobs</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.navBartext{
  text-align: center;
  color:black;
  font-size: 20;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;


}
 #navbar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;


 }
```

Now, when I take the "display: inline;" out of the code, the text aligns vertically instead of horizontally, and then I can use text align to position it, but I want them all in one line. When I use display-inline though it seems to completely circumvent the text-align function (as anything put in here will be ignored). Is there something I'm missing? Perhaps I just don't know enough about the display function.

Comment: The thing you're missing is the width. What's happening will become more obvious if you temporarily add `border: 1px solid red;` or similar to your `.navBartext` element. Block elements (which `div` is, by default) stretch to the width of their container. Inline elements don't. (Also, bear in mind that CSS class names are case-sensitive, so you'll find that in your example, your CSS for `.navBartext` is only applying to your first paragraph, as that's the only one with a capital "B" in the class name.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align the words horizontally, you have to use `display:inline-block;` so that the elements will be treated as text. Always use inline-block for the child elements and `text-align:center;` for the parent.

```
p{
color:black;
font-size: 20;
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 20px;


}
#navbar{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
text-align:center;


}
```

[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rq57v/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, you can use `<ul>` element instead of div, div is better as a wrapper if u need wrap navBar:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/WT7qv][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WT7qv